# SQL Server Profiler - Client unable to establish connection

Tags: connectivity, profiler, ssl, certificate

Spanking brand-new installations of:

- Visual Studio 2022 Community (VS)
- SQL Server 2019 Dev (SQL)
- SQL Server Management Studio v18.10 (SSMS)

There are no other Visual Studio or SQL Server instances or installations.

I can look at my local SQL instance using SSMS but not SQL Server Profiler. I am using Server Name "." and Windows Authentication in both cases. Profiler is being launched both in SSMS and directly launched (in administrative mode or not), with the same results:
[image: SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.]

SQL-related services are in these states (enabling SQL Server Browser has no effect):

[image]

"Trust server certificate" does not help. I suspect the provider is extremely sloppy about the root cause of this response.

(Same system environment as https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70805318/)

Comment: Not that this is necessarily related to your issue, but do you mean you installed [SSMS v18](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) (15 being the build number)?...otherwise SSMS v15 would be a very old version.

Comment: Also, could you post a screenshot of which SQL Server services are currently running? (You could find this if you run the SQL Server Configuration Manager.) Also what happens if you try using `localhost` as the server name?

Comment: The component name is SQL Server Management Studio: 15.0.18390.0. But yes, it says v18.10. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to disable cert verification for the connection by selecting the connection option "Trust the Server Certificate":

[image]

Comment: "Trust server certificate" does not help. I suspect the provider is extremely sloppy about displaying the root cause of this response.

Comment: Check the SQL Log and the Connectivity Ring Buffer: https://github.com/microsoft/CSS_SQL_Networking_Tools/wiki/Collect-the-Connectivity-Ring-Buffer

Comment: The log has: 

Date,Source,Severity,Message,Category,Event,User,Computer
02/05/2022 12:14:51,Schannel,Error,The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this<c/> none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The TLS connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.<nl/> The SSPI client process is PROFILER (PID: 29064).,(0),36882,xxx\yyy,xxx

It would be nice if I could find the "attached data" :-)

Comment: The "ring buffer" has two records: ConnectionClose and LoginTimers with error 17830 - no joy there (https://bobsql.com/sql-mysteries-why-am-i-still-seeing-17830-errors/#:~:text=If%20the%20client%20logged%20in%20and%20never%20sent,Server%2C%20never%20running%20a%20SQL%20command%2C%20and%20disconnecting.)

Comment: I see exactly that behavior if I try to connect using an encrypted connection where SQL uses a self-signed certificate without selecting "trust server certificate".  Perhaps you can use a trusted certificate, or allow unencrypted connections.

Comment: I am using no encryption.